# XJC annotation issue

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I am trying add deprecated annotation on my xjb generated stubs.

```
 <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../../../../server/target/schemas/schema2.xsd">
      <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='someForms']/xs:all/xs:element[@name='detailsForm']">
          <annox:annotate target="getter">@java.lang.Deprecated</annox:annotate>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

It does not fail but does not put xml attribute on the field. This is how xsd looks -

```
<xs:complexType name="approvalForms">
    <xs:all>
       <xs:element name="detailsForm" type="formRef" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

But, the following works

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../../../../server/target/schemas/schema2.xsd">
  <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='someForms']">
     <annox:annotate>
        <annox:annotate annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeName"
           value="SomeForm" />
     </annox:annotate>
  </jaxb:bindings>
```

Am I missing something ? How can I add @Deprecated on getDetailsForm() in stub ?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax actually [looks correct](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/annotate/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb#L17). Might be a bug, please file an issue and provide a test case via PR in this project:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests/annotate

I'll take care of it.

By the way, your customization does not match your XSD: `someForms` vs. `approvalForms`. This might also be a problem - you may be looking in a wrong class.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author.